# Adding WMS layer with extra parameters using QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms, weather

I am not very experienced in GIS in general, but I am trying to add a WMS layer into a QGIS map.

The issue is that this particular layer includes extra parameters.

It's from http://www.bom.gov.au/australia/meteye/, and the specific layer I am trying to bring in is IDZ73013.

When I try to add it in, it doesn't show on the map, probably because I need to specify the rest of the query params. See below example from a URL the website itself sends:

http://wvs3.bom.gov.au/mapcache/meteye?TRANSPARENT=true&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&layers=IDZ73013&TIMESTEP=0&BASETIME=202309050000&ISSUETIME=20230905003726&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&BBOX=144,-54,162,-36&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256

I believe my issues is because I need to pass the BASETIME and TIMESTEP parameters to QGIS, so it can get the right forecast image, but I am not entirely sure how to.

Answer (score 5):

As a workaround it is possible to create the connection to include the extra parameters.

[image]

The GetCapabilities does not contain the extra parameters so these selections are also needed

[image]

Then QGIS shows the map. For using another basetime the connection URL must be edited first.

[image]

Comment: Thanks mate, this is great! But how were you able to use the same color scheme as the website?